# Java Reading in text file and outputting it to new file with removed duplicates

Tags: java, bufferedreader, parseint

I have a text file with an integer on each line, ordered from least to greatest, and I want to put them in a new text file with any duplicate numbers removed.

I've managed to read in the text file and print the numbers on the screen, but I'm unsure on how to actually write them in a new file, with duplicates removed?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("sample.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(str + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll likely need to use a `Set` of some kind, checking to see if the set doesn't contain the value you've read, if it doesn't you add it to the set and write the value to the new file, if it does, you simply discard the value and move on

Comment: Assuming that the input is ordered it is enough to compare every two consecutively read numbers. Thereby you can filter the duplicates just fine. Writing to a File can be done via a `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file, you could add the numbers to a `Set`, which is a data structure that doesn't allow duplicate values (just Google for "java collections" for more details)

Then you iterate through this Set, writing the numbers to a `FileOutputStream` (google for "java io" for more details)

Comment: Is there a way to filter the duplicates without Set? We haven't learned that in my class yet.

Comment: @MC_Gilde As long as you can assert the input is sorted - which you stated in your question - you can do this just fine: Just compare every two consecutively read numbers.

Comment: @MC_Glide Have you learned arrays? You could have an array where position N indicates if the number N has already been read. Assuming that you know the maximum possible number in the file. Or if the file is sorted (numbers are ordered), you just read and compare to the previous one.

Comment: @MC_Glide Sorry, I saw just now that the numbers are ordered. In this case, as previously said, you just compare the number to the previous one (if it's the same, it's a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing each of the numbers, add them to an `Array`. After you've added all the integers, you can cycle through the array to remove duplicates (sample code for this can be found fairly easily).

Once you have an array, use `BufferedWriter` to write to an output file. Example code for how to do this can be found here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Alternatively, use a `Set`, and `BufferedWriter` should still work in the same way.

Comment: You should include your own sample code. The description of what to do seems sound, but it's way better to understand with an example implementation. If you google up a solution, include the relevant part in your answer as a quote because other resources tend to go away.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the input file is already ordered:

```
public class Question42475459 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String inFile = "sample.txt";
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("")), "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inFile + ".out", false))) {

            String lastLine = null;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                final String line = scanner.next();
                if (!line.equals(lastLine)) {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.newLine();
                    lastLine = line;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```